# How to remove one fact in CLIPS using C code using factAddress

Tags: clips

Retract command in CLIPS will remove one fact in CLIPS.
What is equivalent API in C code.

clips.retract  is not working

Comment: Show some code. Otherwhise no answer.

Answer (score 0):

All C APIs for CLIPS are documented in [CLIPS advanced programming guide](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v630/apg.pdf). Check page 105:

```
4.4.23 EnvRetract
int EnvRetract(environment,factPtr);
void *environment;
void *factPtr;
Purpose:
 Retracts a fact from the CLIPS fact-list (the C equivalent of the
CLIPS retract command).
```

Hope this answers your question